# How to encode when writing to file?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I am trying to write some Data to a file. In some instances, obviously depending on the Data I am trying to write, I get a UnicodeEncodeError (UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f622' in position 141: character maps to )
I did some research and found out that I can encode the data I am writing with the encode function.

This is the code prior to modifying it (not supporting Unicode):

```
    scriptDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    path = os.path.join(scriptDir, filename)
    with open(path, 'w') as fp:
        for sentence in iobTriplets:
            fp.write("\n".join("{} {} {}".format(triplet[0],triplet[1],triplet[2]) for triplet in sentence))
            fp.write("\n")
            fp.write("\n")
```

So I though maybe I could just add the encoding when writing like that:

```
fp.write("\n".join("{} {} {}".format(triplet[0],triplet[1],triplet[2]).encode('utf8') for triplet in sentence))
```

But that doesn't work as I am getting the following error:
**TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found**

I also tried opening the file in byte mode with adding a b behind the w. However that didn't yield any results.

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Btw: I am using python 3.

Comment: Please post the original error. Also, I assume this is Python 3?

Comment: the mode should be `encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Probably, yours system has a default encoding that is being picked up by `open`, maybe something like ASCII. So, try using `open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: @C.Nivs either works there. In fact, if it's Python 3, then you can just do `encode()`. I am curious as to why not opening the file in binary mode isn't working.  What does "I also tried opening the file in byte mode with adding a b behind the w. However that didn't yield any results." mean **exactly**

Comment: Anyway, you need to use `b'\n'.join(...)` if you are going to be joining bytes. that is likely the source of your error, but then you will have to use binary mode when opening the file

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are quite right, that was the error. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already opened the file with automatic encoding. There is no need to manually encode anything unless you are writing to binary.
You can specify any supported encoding in `open()`:

```
 with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-16be') as fp:
```

Unless the file is opened as binary, you need to remove the `str.encode()` in the `fp.write()`:

```
fp.write("\n".join("{} {} {}".format(triplet[0],triplet[1],triplet[2]) for triplet in sentence))
```